# is it possible to query Marklogic using XCC without using an 'AdhocQuery'

Tags: java, marklogic

anyone tried to connect to Marklogic using XCC java classes - I want to connect and do a query but not use an 'adhocquery' (xquery) - is this possible? Using the XCC Session or Request classes?

Comment: What is your reason not to use `adhocquery`?

Comment: If by 'query' you mean running a query where the query is not known until runtime,  no.  thats what 'adhoc' means. Run a query where you provide the query.  If by 'query' you mean invoke an existing module passing it parameters then yes, thats what 'invoke' means.  See this example:  https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/examples/doc-files/ModuleRunner.java.txt?hq=xcc%20invoke

Comment: I'm looking for the fastest way to perform queries using java - if that mean invoking a module and you can pass parameters then I guess that's what I would want - i.e. I'm not passing an xquery string, I'm passing some parameters that are a applied to a module in the server

Comment: Whether you use an AdhocQuery or invoke a module should matter far less as to whether your query leverages all the indexes that MarkLogic provides and that can be added. I recommend invoking modules in ML more for code maintenance reasons so that you're not building long queries via string concatentation in Java. Performance is then a matter of how you construct your queries and whether or not they can be fully resolved via indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of executing an adhocQuery, you could invoke a module using request.[newModuleInvoke()](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Session.html#newModuleInvoke-java.lang.String-)

```
String connectionUri = "xcc://user:password@localhost:8888";
String moduleUri = "/some/module.xqy";

ContentSource contentSource = ContentSourceFactory.newContentSource(connectionUri);   
ResultSequence resultSequence = null;

try (Session session = contentSource.newSession()) {
  Request request = session.newModuleInvoke(moduleUri);
  /*
   *if you need to set request parameters, look at the setXXXVariable methods
   * https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Request.html
   * i.e.
   * request.setNewStringVariable("foo", "bar");
   * request.setVariable(xdmVariable); //see also: ValueFactory.newVariable()
   */ 
  resultSequence = session.submitRequest(request);

  //do stuff with the result sequence

} catch (RequestException exc) { 
    //Determine if the exception is retryable or should fail 
} catch (Exception exc) { 
    //Determine what to do with other exceptions 
} finally { 
    //unfortunately, ResultSequence doesn't implement closable...
    if (null != resultSequence && !resultSequence.isClosed()) { 
      resultSequence.close(); 
      resultSequence = null; 
    } 
}
```